# How to combine multiple columns and create unique numeric values

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I want to generate unique records with the combination of two columns and that value must be the same all the time.
For example, I want to concatenate `Col1` ,`Col2` and create `C12`
I want to generate numeric valuse as shown below for the concatenated column.

[image]

my code is this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame({'Col1' : ['Bob', 'Joe', 'Bill', 'Mary', 'Joe'],
              'Col2' : ['Joe', 'Steve', 'Bob', 'Bob', 'Steve'],
               'Col3' : np.random.random(5)})
df['C12'] = df['Col1'] + df['Col2']
df
```

Comment: This not I am expecting. I am expecting 1,2,3 values

Comment: why not using the index ? `df['C12'] = df.index` ?

Comment: df.index solution is nearest .But I want to generate same value for same comined columns. For example JoeSteve value is repetitive. I want single value for this. Please advise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`factorize`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.factorize.html) and add `1` for start from `1`:

```
df['Expected'] = pd.factorize(df['Col1'] + df['Col2'])[0] + 1

print (df)
   Col1   Col2      Col3       C12  Expected
0   Bob    Joe  0.141169    BobJoe         1
1   Joe  Steve  0.324639  JoeSteve         2
2  Bill    Bob  0.792325   BillBob         3
3  Mary    Bob  0.528510   MaryBob         4
4   Joe  Steve  0.779763  JoeSteve         2
```

Answer (score 0):

Another, less elegant solution:

```
# create a lookup C12 => number
lookup = {v:k for k, v in enumerate(df['C12'].drop_duplicates().values)}
# use it for the ID column (here called index)
df['index'] = df.C12.apply(lambda t: lookup[t])
```

Result:

```
  Col1  Col2  Col3    C12    index
0 Bob   Joe 0.272953    BobJoe  0
1 Joe Steve 0.496542  JoeSteve  1
2 Bill  Bob 0.563204    BillBob 2
3 Mary  Bob 0.007123    MaryBob 3
4 Joe Steve 0.182683  JoeSteve  1
```

Answer (score 0):

Use sklearn python library and encode word or alphabet in unique number and every time same word have same number which is unique in complete dataset.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
df = pd.DataFrame({'Col1' : ['Bob', 'Joe', 'Bill', 'Mary', 'Joe'],
              'Col2' : ['Joe', 'Steve', 'Bob', 'Bob', 'Steve'],
               'Col3' : np.random.random(5)})
df['C12'] = df['Col1'] + df['Col2']
labelencoder = LabelEncoder()
df['C12'] = labelencoder.fit_transform(df['C12'])
print(df)
```

Answer (score 0):

Yet another solution for completeness.
In case you expect the values of your combined/concatenated column to contain a lot of repetitions, I would suggest you to make this column `categorical` to safe space and also make processing faster (e.g. if you need to filter on that column or build indexers on it).

You can create it as a categorical column like this:

```
df['C12'] = df['Col1'].str.cat(df['Col2'], na_rep='').astype('category')
```

For the  index column you can then simply use the codes of the category:

```
df['index']= df['C12'].cat.codes
```

Btw. of course the `str.cat` method of combining the two strings is independent from using `category` data types. I could also have concatenated the content as you did it, but `str.cat` seems safer and gives some more control (e.g. you can use arguments like `sep` and `na_rep`). If you look at the following output, you know what I mean.

First created by the method above (note the `na_rep=''`):

```
   Col1   Col2      Col3       C12  index
0   Bob    Joe  0.134319    BobJoe      4
1   Joe  Steve  0.653212  JoeSteve      5
2  Bill    Bob  0.736037   BillBob      3
3  Mary    Bob  0.106365   MaryBob      6
4   Joe  Steve  0.864427  JoeSteve      5
5  Anne   None  0.731624      Anne      1
6  None   Bill  0.736519      Bill      2
7  None   None  0.531170                0

# the corresponding data types are:
Col1       object
Col2       object
Col3      float64
C12      category
index        int8
```

Second by using the following code (note the `NaN`values in the last three rows):

```
df['C12'] = df['Col1'] + df['Col2']
df['index']= df['C12'].astype('category').cat.codes

# Output:
   Col1   Col2      Col3       C12  index
0   Bob    Joe  0.252860    BobJoe      1
1   Joe  Steve  0.092115  JoeSteve      2
2  Bill    Bob  0.105159   BillBob      0
3  Mary    Bob  0.968287   MaryBob      3
4   Joe  Steve  0.047131  JoeSteve      2
5  Anne    NaN  0.241313       NaN     -1
6   NaN   Bill  0.605586       NaN     -1
7   NaN    NaN  0.341819       NaN     -1
```

Both outputs were procuded using the following data (`np.NaN` is just Panda's representation of missing values):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Col1' : ['Bob', 'Joe',   'Bill', 'Mary', 'Joe',  'Anne',  np.NaN,  np.NaN],
              'Col2' :      ['Joe', 'Steve', 'Bob',  'Bob',  'Steve', np.NaN, 'Bill',  np.NaN],
               'Col3' : np.random.random(8)})
```